# Tensorflow : Is there way to feed the crop value (central fraction) to tf.image.central_crop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to central crop images, with different crop fraction for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have the images saved in a list called `images` where `images[0]` is the first one and so on. Lets assume that the central crop fractions lie on the list called `central` where the `central[0]` is the fraction that you want for the first image and so on for `central[i]` for the *i-th* image. Now try this:

```
croped_images = [tf.image.central(i, j) for i, j in zip(images, central)]
```

As a result one get `tf.image.central_crop(images[0], central[0])` from cropping the first image with the first central fraction and so on.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to process only a subsets *n* of your batch then use a generator. This will spare your memory.

```
from itertools import izip

def gen_central_cropped(images, central, n):
    for i in range(0, len(images), n):
        yield [tf.image.central_crop(img,fraction) for img, fraction in izip(images[i:i+n],central[i:i+n])]

func = gen_central_cropped

for n_central_croped in func(images, central, n):
    #write or process n central cropped images here
```

So, you read in your program from your 70k images training set a batch of lets say 256. You want to central crop this batch with different fractions  but your memory can not handel it. Then use the generator with an acceptable sub_batch *n*, lets say 10. Now your memory will hold only 10 cropped images at a time. You can either write them in another dataset or process them further then write/delete them.

Comment: Though I didn't check your answer yet. I think, at least in my case, images are so big in size and there are about 70K images that cannot be loaded all at once